# Accidentally grown oak trees

Tags: trees

We have accidentally grown oak trees and our garden is simply not big enough to accommodate them what should we do with them please?

Comment: Are they in the ground and if so, how big are they? Photos might help

Answer (score 3):

Cut them, repeatedly (or uproot them if they are still quite small and you can do that) unless you can find someone who wants to take them via transplanting before they get any larger.

Like any other plant growing where you don't want it, it's a weed.